# Android custom buttons layout

Tags: android, layout

How can I create buttons like the "ABN Amro Bankieren" application for the Netherlands with onclick handlers?

[Screenshot ABN Amro app](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/5411/20110827124439.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You have to make 2 pressed and normal (it may be 4 for focused and disabled) xml layout for each 3 top, center and bottom buttons.
This is example xml for the center button for normal state is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#F7FCF6"/>
    <stroke android:width="2sp" android:color="#9FA89F"/>      
</shape>
```

to make it rounded corner you may use corner tag for top button

```
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1sp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0.1sp" android:topLeftRadius="7sp"
android:topRightRadius="7sp" />
```

this may cause problem in xml layout editer but will be fine on emulator or real device

Comment: damn, if i have to create at least 2 xml documents for all the buttons, that destroys my folder structure :')

and with <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#9FA89F"/> I set 1px border all around.. but how can I add a border just on the sides?

Comment: Then better is to add [9 patch Images](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) of the button and you can achieve you desired.