# Android equivalent of iPhone grouped cell layout

Tags: android, android-widget

I have this screenshot from my iPhone; I'm trying to make the same layout in Android.  I finished the buttons on the left, but now I'm working on the group of four white buttons on the right.

I think they are styled as UITableViewstyleGrouped.

They remind me of [segmented layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5842909/194309) but segmented layouts are basically radio buttons, while these are not.

Is there an android version of these?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7214062/593709)

Comment: ah!  you got me started on a good track with the shape tag.  I found a more fully elaborated version http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726352/194309  I'll mix yours with that and hopefully can get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `ListView`.

More about `ListView` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) or for a custom `ListView` tutorial [check this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html).