# How to create an iOS style arrow button in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am partial to dual use buttons in iOS, like in the image below:

[image]

How can I create these types of buttons in Android?  In other words, the entire button must be clickable, the arrow must be right-aligned and the text of the button must be left aligned.

I tried playing with a regular Button widget, but no luck.  Do I have to resort to a Table layout (but then the clickability would be lost).

Comment: You should not give a android device user a iOS look & feel. I friendly suggesting to use android common layout.

Comment: @Grrbrr404 Can suggest a style for Android that accomplishes what I need (e.g. provides information and performs action)?

Comment: Example: http://netbookscoop.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/android-settings.png type "android settings" into google pictures

Comment: @AngryHacker every view in Android can define an onclicklistener. You could therefore create a layout that is clickable as a whole. But the rightdrawable solution from Adil Soomro should be the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need customized shape background for the `Button`

You can find [customizing shape here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214172/593709)

Set that background to the `Button` from xml, and for showing arrow, you will need to add `arrow.png` to your project drawables.

you will add attribute to button like this:

```
<Button android:backround="@drawable/cell_background"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow" ...  />
```