# How do you make a pointed Button? (Arrow-like)

Tags: android, button

How do you make this type of button?
I think it is Android 4+ and it's often seen in Google's applications.

[image]

Comment: You need to design image for this

Comment: This might help you: [How to create an iOS style arrow button in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586522/how-to-create-an-ios-style-arrow-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a rectangular image draw the arrow shape filled with any color you want for background and leave the 2 triangles that fill the rectangle (outside the arrow) white. Save the file as .png and use it as a background of a button. The white triangles will be drawn as transparent.

You can also make it 9 patch to allow different text lengths inside the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can create image in `Photoshop` by making some part `Transparent`

Comment: Okay, I assumed it was some built-in thing